# Change an Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

i have this code:

```
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT groupid  FROM user_groups WHERE userid=?");
$sth->execute(array($uid));
$sth->execute();

$results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);// EIndimensionale Array
print_r($results);
```

This bring me this output:
Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 9 )

But I need a output like this:
13, 9

Can you pleas give me the right hint...
Thanks a lot

Comment: You execute your query twice!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
implode(",", $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this before print_r

```
$results = implode(",",$results);
```

Good luck!